# problems updating picture box control

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two controls on the  same form. Both controls contain an [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) control. The one listview was created with the graphical editor in visual studio. This one is not causing any issues.  The other listview is created programmatically at run-time. I have defined an event handler for each control that gets called when the hot item changes and they are both firing when they should. Both event handlers call the same code to update a picturebox control. The problem is that the picturebox does not get updated when the programmatically defined listview is asking it to. I am positive the event handler is getting called because my code writes to a text file as well as updating the picture box. The text file gets updated  but the picture box does not. I have tried updating, invalidating, and refreshing the PicutureBox as well as the parent form, but I just can not get it to update.

I am not sure if this is an ObjectListView issue or a standard WinForms problem.  I realize my question is very vague but I am not sure how to clarify it without posting all my code.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Here is the code that the event handler calls:

```
    public void ShowBitmap(object sender, HotItemChangedEventArgs e, ObjectListView lv, string type)
    {

        ObjectListView olv = sender as ObjectListView;
        if (sender == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        switch (e.HotCellHitLocation)
        {
            case HitTestLocation.Nothing:
                break;
            case HitTestLocation.Group:
                break;
            case HitTestLocation.GroupExpander:
                break;
            default:
                if (e.HotColumnIndex == 0)
                {
                    pictureBox1.Hide();
                    pictureBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
                    int rowIndex = e.HotRowIndex;
                    string text = "";
                    if (type == "Main Parts")
                    {
                        TypedObjectListView<MainRadanProjectPartsPart> tlist = new TypedObjectListView<MainRadanProjectPartsPart>(lv);
                        text = tlist.Objects[rowIndex].Symbol;
                    }
                    else if (type == "Parts")
                    {
                        TypedObjectListView<RadanProjectPartsPart> tlist = new TypedObjectListView<RadanProjectPartsPart>(lv);
                        text = tlist.Objects[rowIndex].Symbol;
                    }
                    else if (type == "Nests")
                    {
                        TypedObjectListView<MainRadanProjectNestsNest> tlist = new TypedObjectListView<MainRadanProjectNestsNest>(lv);
                        text = tlist.Objects[rowIndex].FileName;
                    }

                    if (text != null)
                    {
                        Point screenCoords = Cursor.Position;
                        Point controlRelatedCoords = lv.PointToClient(screenCoords);

                        if (controlRelatedCoords.Y < oldCursorPosition.Y)
                        {
                            pictureBox1.Location = controlRelatedCoords;
                            int xPos = controlRelatedCoords.X;
                            int yPos = controlRelatedCoords.Y + 60;
                            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(xPos, yPos);
                        }
                        else if (controlRelatedCoords.Y > oldCursorPosition.Y)
                        {
                            pictureBox1.Location = controlRelatedCoords;
                            int xPos = controlRelatedCoords.X;
                            //int yPos = controlRelatedCoords.Y - pictureBox1.Height;
                            int yPos = controlRelatedCoords.Y - pictureBox1.Height + 30;
                            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(xPos, yPos);
                        }

                        pictureBox1.Show();
                        pictureBox1.BringToFront();
                        olvTreeViewMainParts.Focus();
                        lv.Focus();
                        pictureBox1.Visible = true;
                        DrawSymbol(text);

                        oldCursorPosition = controlRelatedCoords;   // save the cursor position to track cursor direction between calls
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DrawSymbol("");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    pictureBox1.Hide();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Here is the event handler for the programmaticaly defined listview:

```
     // track the cursor as it moves over the items in the listview
    private void olvPartsListView_HotItemChanged(object sender, HotItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ShowBitmap(sender, e, olvPartsListView, "Parts"); 
    }
```

Comment: Side note: "ordinary controls" are the once that have code for them in .designer.cs file? Just look there and see if setup is totally different from you run-time created one...

Comment: There is no difference between the actual controls, the difference is in how and where the code is written. One you write your self, the other gets auto generated with some default values by the designer and as @AlexeiLevenkov said you can find that code in the .designer.cs file

Comment: you should consider updating your question a bit... your question is not really "what are the differences between...." it is, "I tried to update this control and it didn't update."  You will get better responses if you ask about your problem, not what other factors might play a role.  Somewhat the XY problem. The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.

That is, you are trying to solve problem X, and you think solution Y would work, but instead of asking about X when you run into trouble, you ask about Y.

Comment: show the code that is calling the function, not the function itself.

Comment: also, where is `pictureBox1` declared?

Comment: PictureBox1 is defined on the main (root) form. The listview that works is on a tab page on a tab control on the first panel of a split container on the main form. The listview that does not work is on a tab page on a tab control on a tab page on a tab control on the second panel of the same split container. (The second listview has an extra tab control underneath it)

Comment: without seeing where the variable pictureBox1 (note the case) is declared, I would have to guess that you have a reference to it within one tab page but no reference to it in the second.